Issue with OR condition in snowflake
why is the not equal condition working in snowflake ?
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ( COLUMN1 <> 'VALUE1' OR COLUMN2 <> 'VALUE1')
The above statement does not work  whereas the below statement works
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE not ( COLUMN1 = 'VALUE1' OR COLUMN2 = 'VALUE1')
Edited the description
The requirement is to get all records from a table  where  column1 should not have 'value1' or column2 should not have value1  .
I believe this is something specific to how snowflake does the equality and non equality comparison

You’re going to have to be a bit more specific about the problem you’re experiencing. Staying that something “doesn’t work” isn’t particularly descriptive and can mean a variety of different things to different people. Provide a sample DDL alongside these queries to complete your [mre].

@esqew hope its  not   a minimal reproducible example now

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws. not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B). Your first query is (not A) or (not B), so the equivalent is not (A and B). But your second query is not (A or B), which isn't an equivalent query, hence why one works and the other doesn't.

Your question is still not minimally reproducible. Here's an example of a minimally reproducible example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/74BBuLHnan9jYHkpnnrtEB/0

Your statements are not equivalent.
If this works...
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE not ( COLUMN1 = 'VALUE1' OR COLUMN2 = 'VALUE2')

Then the correct with not-equals is...
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ( COLUMN1 <> 'VALUE1' AND COLUMN2 <> 'VALUE2')

So it should be an AND in the not-equals version, not OR

thats not exactly what is required ,the column value can exist in either on the column .if it exists in column1 and not in column2 ,it should not return records

Updated to include truth table for null values. Note also that the correct SQL does not change even with null values.
Going by your statement that the second statement is giving the right results, the first statement should be changed to SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (COLUMN1 <> 'VALUE1' AND COLUMN2 <> 'VALUE1'). The truth tables for NOT(A OR B) are the same for NOT(A) AND NOT(B). In the table below, your first SQL is in column 3, your second SQL is in column 4, and the correct SQL that gives the same values as your first SQL is in column 5:



A
B
A <> VALUE1 OR B <> VALUE1
NOT(A = VALUE1 OR B = VALUE1)
A <> VALUE1 AND B <> VALUE1




VALUE1
VALUE1
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE


VALUE1
XYZ
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE


XYZ
VALUE1
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE


XYZ
XYZ
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE


VALUE1
NULL
NULL
FALSE
FALSE


NULL
VALUE1
NULL
FALSE
FALSE


XYZ
NULL
TRUE
NULL
NULL


NULL
XYZ
TRUE
NULL
NULL


NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL



Note that if you only want rows where both COLUMN1 and COLUMN2 have 'VALUE1' as you mentioned in the comments, then your second SQL will not work either. It would help if you give example data and example expected results to help determine what exactly is required.

my requirement as stated before is that if column1 or column2 contains 'VALUE1' ,the record shouldnt be fetched.I tried using  select * from table where ( column1 <> 'VALUE1' OR column2 <> 'VALUE1')  this doesnt seem to work in snowflake unlike other databases

OK, so if you look at the table above, the only row that will be returned is when neither COLUMN1 nor COLUMN2 are equal to 'VALUE1'. This is working as expected on Snowflake. Again, unless you can provide sample data and expected results, no further help is possible.

if the table column contains  null ,its not working
